# How to create the bubble like this image ? in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

[image]

There are several apps that provide speech bubble, And I'd like to know how to create the bubbles like one in the sample image.

The bubble's length is adjusted according to the size of the text.
To make the speech bubble like one in the sample image, Should i use 
"Quartz Core framework" ?

Please Help Me !

Comment: you have 0% accept rating

Comment: Isn't that done by a simple scaling of a vector image ?

Comment: @tulurira Did you figure it out? IT would be great if you can share it. thanks